# Adding functions for organization to my python script

Tags: python, pandas, organization

I have a really long python script that I need to consolidate into functions for code organization.

```
#function here?
import nltk
import collections
counts = collections.Counter()
for sent in df["messages"]:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    counts.update(nltk.bigrams(words))
counts = {k: v for k, v in counts.items() if v > 150}

print('\n','bigram counter finished!')

#function here?
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts,orient='index').reset_index()
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=0,ascending=False)
#creating a list of the bigrams after being sorted
my_bigrams = list(df2['index'])
my_bigrams = [i for i in my_bigrams if i[1] != i[0]]
#taking the top 500 bigrams
#my_bigrams = my_bigrams[0:499]
print('\n','duplicate bigrams removed!')

#function here?
pat = '|'.join(" ".join(x) for x in my_bigrams)
df['bigram'] = df['message'].str.findall(pat)
df = df.applymap(str)
df = df.drop(['message'], axis=1)
df["bigram"] = df.bigram.str[1:-1].str.split(",\s").map(set)



#function here?
df = df.applymap(str)
df['bigram'] = df['bigram'].str.replace('[^\w\s,]','')
df["bigram"] = df.bigram.str.split(",\s").map(list)
df = df.applymap(str)
df['bigram'] = df['bigram'].str.replace('[^\w\s,]','')



#function here?
df = df.sort_values(by='date')
def update_col(col):
    col[:] = col.iloc[0]
    return col
df['date'] = df.groupby('room').date.apply(update_col)
```

I am having trouble putting the code into functions.  I don't understand how to organized this code into functions to make it neater.  Any suggestions?  fyi, this is just some random code I have so not looking to make this run, just ideas on what parameters to pass, how many parameters, how I could make this neater.  Every I have '#function here?' in the code above I am looking to make a function if that makes sense.

Comment: you don't have to make functions if the logic isn't breakable. If you can break the script down into parts like: get_converted_data, process_data, multiply_tables, etc. it makes sense to break it.

Comment: If I semi-close my eyes and read your code fast, I make no idea of what you are doing. It is full of details everywhere. If you identify the tasks you are doing with function names and call them sequentially, you add so much readability that anyone can read what your are doing without considering the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited header :: The following situations suggest grouping code into functions:

A. Redundancy : See if same task is getting performed on different set of data. If yes, put it into a function and make the call.

B. Control Flow : If the code has a set of atomic tasks, logically speaking, that must be performed in a sequence, create a function for each such task irrespective of redundancy.

C. Consistency : Often debugging requires tracing of code to its root problem. If you feel a set of lines describe an action of sorts, put it in a function, it will pinpoint the problem to exact location in a fine manner.

D. Data transformation : If a piece of data is transforming into another format, for example, tree to doubly linked list, you should create a function for that.

Comment: I would edit to "The following situations suggest grouping code into functions".

Comment: I'll do it immediately.